# Automated e2e testing- WebDriverJS, Jasmine

Tags: node.js, selenium, angularjs-e2e, jasmine-node

I'm following this tutorial 
http://engineering.wingify.com/posts/e2e-testing-with-webdriverjs-jasmine/

First part calls for creating testfile.js

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
    build();

driver.get('http://www.wingify.com');
```

I was able to get the browser to run when I run node testfile.js

I create the testfile.js

$ cat testfile.js

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
    build();

describe('basic test', function () {
    it('should be on correct page', function () {
        driver.get('http://www.wingify.com');
        driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
            expect(title).toBe('Wingify');
        });
    });
});
```

I get to this part where you run jasmine-node

```
$ jasmine-node testfile.js 

Finished in 0 seconds
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

The expected behavior is that it launches the browser but that is not what I am experiencing.

Comment: The Wingify blog post continues by explaining why you need to add `done`, so the code sample you posted is not really supposed to work. Still, you should see a browser being launched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the timeout value by calling:

```
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 9999999;
```

Take a look at [this example gist](https://gist.github.com/christian-bromann/6416864) (I used [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io) here).

Answer (score 4):

Try `jasmine-node --matchall testfile.js` or `jasmine-node testfile.spec.js`, by default jasmine-node searches for files containing "spec" in file name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing. driver.getTitle() is asynchronous, therefore Jasmine completes before anything is returned.  I tried several things using driver.wait() but could not get the async right.

In the end I used Jasmine waitsFor - this waits for a true result, or it has it's own custom timeout.

My example below is slightly more complicated, as I load Google, do a search then check the page title on the results.

With this example you don't need to set the global Jasmine timeout, which for me didn't work anyway.

```
describe('basic test', function () {

    it('should search for webdriver and land on results page', function () {
        var match = 'webdriver - Google Search',
            title = '';

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name("q")).sendKeys("webdriver");
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name("btnG")).click();

        // wait for page title, we know we are there
        waitsFor(function () {
            driver.getTitle().then(function (_title) {
                title = _title;
            });
            return title === match;
        }, 'Test page title, so we know page is loaded', testTimeout);

        // test title is correct
        runs(function () {
            expect(title).toEqual(match);
        });
    });
});
```

The waitsFor polls until a true result is returned, at that point the following runs() executes.  It seems little long winded for me especially as it doing a comparison twice, once for the waits and again for the jasmine assertion.

I did another example using mocha instead of jasmine, using assert library, did have this problem.

Comment: Hi Will, It will be of great help if you can point me to some link that provides the tutorial / api reference to web driver / jasmine / selenium web UI testing.